# Hyperlink to new workbook broken

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-2010

I'm new to Excel so I hope this makes sense. The code below shows a new sheet being created on a specific workbook (separate from the current one) when a button on a user form is clicked. Though, my hyperlink to the sheet created on the separate workbook seems to be broken. What am I doing wrong? Anything helps, thanks!

```
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Employee Information")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Me.cbStores.Value = "Northern" Then
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set newWB = GetOrCreateWB("EmployeeTemplates", "C:\Users\...\Folder") '<--| Opening EmployeeTemplates wb
thisWB.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=newWB.Sheets(1)
With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
    .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
End With
End If
```

Comment: Where/how do you declare `ws` and `LastRow`? How is the link "broken"?

Comment: Its just putting the hyperlink on my main page sheet on a cell that's blank that's all. I don't think that's the issue. Its supposed to be linked to the newly created page on the separate workbook but its not.

Comment: Address is empty

Comment: What should the Address contain, like I said I'm new to Excel

Comment: `LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count)` should likely be `LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count)...` to make sure you count the rows on `ws`.  The address is the address of the hyperlink - see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me find a proper solution, so here it is:

```
ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), Address:=newWB.Path & "\" & newWB.Name, SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 01

This answer uses the file path such as "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\newfile.xlsx"

```
With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
    .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + _
            AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + _
            AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it

    ' the hyperlink SubAddress needs a valid file path or hyperlink to
    ' work like "C:\User\me\Desktop\newfile.xlsx" 
    ' .Name & "!A1" references a cell not the file location on the computer 
    ' or network
    'ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), _
    '                  Address:="", SubAddress:=.Name & "!A1", _
    '                  TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet

    ' you need something like this
    ' as long as newWB.Path property is set you should be good
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), _
                      Address:="", SubAddress:=newWB.Path, _
                      TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
End With
```

### Answer 02

This answer uses a reference which is what you originally wanted.  I'm having trouble finding the link to the stack overflow question but I tested the code and it works.  I liked this option but it only works as long as the workbook is in the same Excel application.  If you have two applications open it will not work because there is no reference to the new workbook in the application.

```
With ActiveSheet '<--| the just pasted worksheet becomes the active one
    .Name = AddEmployeeUF.txtFirstname.Text + _
            AddEmployeeUF.txtMiddleinitial.Text + _
            AddEmployeeUF.txtLastname.Text + "Template" '<--| Name it

    ' the hyperlink SubAddress needs a valid file path or hyperlink to
    ' work like "C:\User\me\Desktop\newfile.xlsx" 
    ' .Name & "!A1" references a cell not the file location on the computer 
    ' or network
    'ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), _
    '                  Address:="", SubAddress:=.Name & "!A1", _
    '                  TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet

    ' you need something like this
    ' as long as newWB.Path property is set you should be good
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("F" & LastRow), _
                      Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!A1", _
                      TextToDisplay:="View" '<--| hyperlink to new sheet
End With
```

Comment: That is interesting.  You will need to put the name in a string then add the string to the hyperlink if I'm reading this correctly: string_name = .Name then in the hyperlink statement: SubAddress  = "'" & string_name & "'!A1".  That will tell me if the .Name is referencing a different sheet.  This worked for me in a test case.  If it doesn't work let me know and post your code so I can see it.

Comment: Invalid or unqualified reference error string_name = .Name